# Confused by spelling

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

My Mom likes to sew clothes in the bedroom. My Dad likes to sow seeds in the garden. On Fridays, they both like to ---.

Is there any way this can be completed properly?

Comment: **so and so** ?

Comment: Please clarify.  Are you looking of punny expression, or do you honestly believe that completing your sentence would be legitimate serious English?

Comment: *...they both like to read Kurt Vonnegut's novel "Slaughterhouse-Five"* (where the phrase "**So it goes**" [appears 106 times](https://booksien.com/2017/03/13/about-so-it-goes/)).

Comment: >...they both like to engage in their hobbies.

Answer (score 1):

Spoken out loud,

> "My mother likes to sew clothes in the bedroom and my father seeds in the garden"

is proper [zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis).

And likewise

> /ðeɪ boʊθ laɪk tu: soʊ/

Comment: Your sentence in IPA is best understood as the answer to a riddle: My mother likes to do it in the bedroom and my father in the garden.